# Is there a way to get IBM Ilog Elixir 3.0 working in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: flex4.5, flash-builder, ilog, ilog-elixir

I've installed IBM ILOG Elixir 3.0 on my Flash Builder 4.5 installation. 
I'm trying to use the IBM ILOG components inside a Flex 4.5 project, but I get;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\Elixir 3.0\frameworks\libs\ilog-elixir.swc- DesignAssetLoader.CompleteTimeout

SWC file failed to load. Any component dependent on this SWC file will not be displayed in the Design Mode.
The SWC may have failed to load because of: 
*  Incompatible definitions caused by usage of a different SDK version  
*  Missing referred class definitions
```

Officially there's no support for the combination Flash Builder 4.5 (Flex SDK 4.5) with IBM Ilog Elixir [according to the IBM Ilog Elixir Product Forum](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=372155&tstart=0) but I hope someone created a way to use them together!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a SDK 4.5 compliant advanced calendar component, you can check this one : http://www.flex-component.com

Comment: Thanks Patrick the suggested calendar component looks great. But I would like to use the IBM Ilog Elixir components not only for the calendar but for the heat maps and the diagrams as well.